# How can I execute a statement AFTER a loop finishes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm querying a mongo database to retrieve the tiles for the display in rougelike game. This is the function I use:

```
function get_display(){
    var collections = ['austinsroom'];
    var db  = mongojs(uri, collections);
    var temphtml = '';

    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        console.log("y=" + String(j));
        db.austinsroom.find({"y": j}, {}).sort({"x": 1}, function(err, records) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("There was an error executing the database query.");
                return;
            } 
            var i = records.length;
            while(i--) {
                temphtml += records[i].display;
            }   
            temphtml += '<br>';
            //console.log(temphtml);
            //return temphtml;
            //THE ONLY WAY I CAN GET ANYTHING TO PRINT IN THE CONSOLE IS IF I PUT IT INSIDE THE LOOP HERE
            });
        //console.log(temphtml);
        //return temphtml;
        //THIS DOES NOTHING
    }
    //console.log(temphtml);
    //return temphtml;
    //THIS DOES NOTHING
}
get_display();
```

If I put the `console.log(temphtml)` inside the loop, it prints out three times which isn't what I want. I only want the final string (i.e. `...<br>...<br>...<br>`. Also I can't ultimately return the `temphtml` string, which is actually the important thing. Is this some quirk of javascript? Why would it not execute statements after the loop?

Also: is there a better way to retrieve every element of a grid that's stored in a mongo database, in order, so it can be displayed properly? Here's what the mongo documents look like:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "570a8ab0e4b050965a586957"},
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "display": "."
}
```

Right now, the game is supposed to display a "`.`" in all empty spaces using the x and y values for the coordinates. The database is indexed by "x" values.

Comment: I'm not sure what `db.austinsroom.find` is but is it an asynchronous function? If it is then that means the for loop might finish before the `db.austinsroom.find` call in which case the `temphtml` variable will have nothing in it...

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Is correct about `db.austinsroom.find` being asynchronous (notice the call back function). Sounds like what you want is loop through `db.austinsroom.find` 1,2,3 THEN print. Since 1,2,3 contain asynchronous calls, you will need to find a way to know when they have all completed (or failed). Look into using promises

Comment: @KarlGalvez but there are ways to actually either "loop" with async flow control, or build the list of promises to return. Noting that the `mongojs` driver does not itself support promises, but other drivers for MongoDB do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`async.whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst). You want flow control of the `for` loop, for which this provides a callback to control each loop iteration.

```js
var temphtml = "",
    j = 0;

async.whilst(
  function() { return j < 3 },
  function(callback) {
    db.austinsroom.find({"y": j }, {}).sort({"x": 1}, function(err, records) 
      temphtml += records.map(function(el) {
          return el.display;
      }).join("") + '<br>';
      j++;
      callback(err);
    });
  },
  function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(temphtml);
  }
)
```

Either that or use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on collected promises to return "one big result". But you would also need to switch to [`promised-mongo`](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo) from `mongojs`, as the nearest equivalent, since there are more mongodb drivers that actually support promises. That one is just the direct fork from `mongojs`:

```js
var temphtml = "",
    j = 0,
    promises = [];

for ( var j=0; j < 3; j++ ) {
   promises.push(db.austinsroom.find({"y": j }, {}).sort({"x": 1}).toArray());
   promises.push('<br>');   // this will just join in the output
)

Promise.all(promises).then(function(records) {
    temphtml += records.map(function(el) {
        return el.display;
    }).join("");
})
```

Not exactly the same thing, since it's one list output and not three, but the point is that the `Promise` objects defer until actually called to resolve, so you can feed the paramters in the loop, but execute later.

Comment: Your first solution worked great with after I npm installed async. I still don't quite understand why or promises, but that's totally on me :/

Comment: @AustinCapobianco What the answer is showing you is the `async.whilst` has a `callback` on the iterator, so the next loop is only called when that `callback` is called from inside the resulting `.find()` callback. Promises, mean that the `.find()` statements do not actually execute but actually return a "promise". These are then all "resolved" ( executed ) with the `.then()`. But with `Promise.all()` they happen all at once and "combine" output as a single array. Aside from dependencies, the difference is in sequence of execution. Either serial, or "all at once" respectively.

Comment: I still don't get the purpose of the `callback(err);` after an iteration. Also while `console.log(temphtml)` works, I can't figure out how to make the function return the `temphtml` string. It just says the result is undefined when I try `console.log(get_display());`

Comment: @AustinCapobianco Because you are doing it wrong. Read ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which basically contains the definitive answers on the subject. As to the `callback(err)`, keep looking and reading further and work it out. Once you understand callbacks it becomes quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use MongoDB but from what I am reading it is asynchronous. So what is happening is your `db.austinsroom.find` call fires another "thread" and returns to the for loop to continue the next iteration.

One way to do what you want is have a check at the end of your `db.austinsroom.find` function to see if you're done with the for loop. Something like:

```
function get_display()
{
    var collections = ['austinsroom'];
    var db  = mongojs(uri, collections);
    var temphtml = '';
    var doneCounter = 0;

    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        console.log("y = " + String(j));
        db.austinsroom.find({"y": j}, {}).sort({"x": 1}, function(err, records)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("There was an error executing the database query.");
                return;
            } 
            var i = records.length;
            while(i--)
            {
                temphtml += records[i].display;
            }   
            temphtml += '<br>';

            // we're done with this find so add to the done counter
            doneCounter++;

            // at the end, check if the for loop is done
            if(doneCounter == 3)
            {
                // done with all three DB calls
                console.log(temphtml);
            }
       });
    }
}
```

This is probably not the best way as I know nothing about MongoDB but it should put you on the right path.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work. This doesn't make any sense to me. I even tried "j=1" and "j=2" in the if statement, but nothing worked...

Comment: Promises are still the better answer IMO, but will require getting your mongodb calls to return them. However, I think this solution will work if you use `function(err, records, j)` currently this function doesn't know about `j`(i think). If not, try to log the value of j before the `if(j == 3)` statement

Comment: When I call `console.log(temphtml)` in the if statement, it just gives me the blank `temphtml=''` from when I initialized it, regardless of what j is. The j value is coming out fine. I'm trying to figure out promises now, but I don't really understand them.

Comment: I see the issue now. The order the `db.austinsroom.find` is not guaranteed to be in 1,2,3 order.

Comment: And yes, `Promise` would be better but not sure how much of a pain it'll be to implement with MongoDB.